# Send an email from core data

Tags: ios

I want to create an app like CoreDataBooks example http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html . My idea is, after fill data into fields send an email with this new data. Is this possible and how I can do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending Mail in **Background** is only possible with a Webservice. You can install some php scripts on a webhost,... than you have a Webservice.
You can then send your email data with a `NSMutableURLRequest` throughout `NSURLConnection`.

If you want to send Mails in front with the internal Mail framework (MFMailComposeViewController), you should look [here](http://www.iostipsandtricks.com/using-apples-mail-composer/).